# How can I find the reason for a ban through discord audit logs? (Using Discord.js)

Tags: discord.js

What I'm trying to do is make a log for my bot, (you know, something to record server events as they happen), and I've been doing alright so far, but I just can't seem to figure out how to get the reason for a ban/kick or whatever else can record reasons. I've checked the documentation, and I just can't really figure out what some of the stuff there means. There isn't really code to show off, because I have no clue where to start here, and it's about time I ask somewhere for help.

Edit: I do know where to start, I can find the audit log entry, but I can't get the reason for the entry

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: i'm using version 12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`guild.fetchAuditLogs()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=fetchAuditLogs)

```js
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('Guild_ID')
const fetchedBan = await guild.fetchAuditLogs({ user: 'User_ID), type: 'MEMBER_BAN_ADD' })
```

You can also use `message.guild` instead of `const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('Guild_ID')`

To get the reason for the latest ban of that member

```js
const banReason = fetchedBan.entries.first().reason
```

Comment: I know how to find the audit log entry, which is my fault for not specifying that, so sorry. What I don't understand is how to find the reason for that entry.

Comment: I fixed my answer, I want you to console.log(fetchedBan) and post the output

Comment: `GuildAuditLogs {
  webhooks: Collection [Map] {},
  integrations: Collection [Map] {},
  entries: Collection [Map] {}
}`